# How do I solve the issue when I get "pip isn't recognized" error in Django virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip

I have created virtualenv for my Django project and I have already installed some packages also. But after a certain time, when I try to download another package, it says "pip is not recognized".

What can be the issue and how would I solve this?

Comment: What commands did you use to create the virtual environment and start it? Have you tried `python -m pip`?

Comment: I used virtualenv env to create the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following command in the same virtual environment to solve this issue.

```
python -m ensurepip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced similar issue. It might be because of pip version. You might have updated pip as shown in the command line.
Just create another environment and don't update pip there. It will work for you.